# Why are effective divisors the same thing as curves on $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

In Vakil's FOAG, Chapter $20$, he starts section $20.2$ by writing

> Let $X$ be a regular projective surface, and $C$ and $D$ be effective divisors (i.e., curves) on $X$ ...

My question is, why are effective divisors on $X$ the same thing as curves on $X$? I understand that divisors, up to linear equivalence, are the same as invertible sheaves because $Pic(X)$ is isomorphic to $Cl(X)$, and I understand that invertible ideal sheaves on $X$ are the same as effective *cartier* divisors, which are the same as curves on $X$ because these are closed subschemes $Y\hookrightarrow X$ cut out locally by one non-zero-divisor, so in particular $\dim Y=1$, i.e. $Y$ is a curve. It seems just a few more logical steps should give the correspondence Vakil uses here, but I don't see it immediately. It's probably been covered prior in the book, but I've skipped around sections a bit and must have missed it.

Comment: You write - I understand that divisors up to linear equivalence.....- What is a divisor for you?

Comment: @Mohan a Weil divisor is an element of the free abelian group on the set of irreducible codimension $1$ subschemes of $X$, yes? And two divisors $D,D'$ are linearly equivalent if they differ by $\text{div}(s)$ for some rational function $s$ on $X$.

Comment: Isn't a codimension one irreducible subscheme on a surface a curve?

Comment: @Mohan Yeah I started to make that connection when I answered your question. What I don't get though, is if $C$ is a curve in $X$ then $C$ and $2C$ are distinct divisors, so under this correspondence must be distinct curves. What curve is represented by $2C$ then?

Comment: $2C$ is an effective divisor, not a curve, but one loosely uses the same word.

Comment: Well $2C$ isn't the same "curve" as $C$, it is $C$ "doubled", in the same sense that you speak of a "double line".
More precisely, a closed subscheme of codimension 1 is locally defined by one regular equation since your surface is regular. If $f$ is a locally defining equation, then $f^2$ defines a different closed subscheme, for instance if the scheme defined by $f$ is reduced, then the one defined by $f^2$ won't be. Of course the reduced underlying subscheme is the same or if you want the irreduible closed subset is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambiguity detected is between curves and *reduced* curves. The line $2L$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$ is the same set as $L$, but "considered with multiplicity $2$". We could just consider that to be a psychological state on the part of the reader, or a device in calculating—so that we can multiply $2L$ by a different curve $C$ and get number $2(C.L)$.

However, the ideal $(x^2)$ is not the same as $(x)$. In scheme theory, we want to take $2L$ to be the set $L$, but with coordinate ring$$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x^2).$$"Functions on $2L$" then include the function $x$ which takes the value $0$ at every point, but has nonzero derivative in the transverse direction to $L$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$.

An effective divisor is$$D = \sum n_i C_i.$$If we only look at the point set, we do not see the $n_i$. We might want to consider the $n_i$ as artificially added multiplicities, for example to make Bézout's theorem work. Or we might want to consider $D$ with its coordinate ring$$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/\left(\prod f_i^{n_i}\right).$$There are various games we can play with these kinds of rings, including localization.

Comment: Was just looking back at my questions and noticed I had never responded to this. This answer did help me a lot at the time though so thank you!